# CSS : Trying to reproduce input with div+input but having a bad top padding

Tags: html, css, padding

I will make a jQuery plugin for one of my projects, and I am trying to simulate an input with divs and spans to make it "richer".

Instead of having [ input ], I will have [ span (containing a A for removing) + input] so the user will not see the difference because he will be typing on a real input without borders, and the result (when accepted) will appear in a small rectangular box at the left of the field.

But I have one problem: there's always a gap between the top of the div and the span containing the left text. Same for the input, the two do not have the same margin for the top and bottom.
I am trying to remove that incorrect top margin (or padding), it looks like 3px from the top and 2px for the bottom. I seem to have tried everything and I always end up to have **too much pixels** on the top of the span & input.

---

**I have reproduced my problem here (only a few lines of css code):**

http://jsfiddle.net/JB9Uq/1/

---

```
<div class="input-reference"><span>Content in span <a href="#"><i class="icon-remove">x</i></a></span><input type="text"></div>
```

I'd need some assistance on that, I tried margins, paddings, line height, display:inline-block... but it still does not seem to work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting issue, it is definitely font-size and thus font-related. E.g., try setting font-size to 55px on the span and everything looks perfect. Have you tried a different font-family?

Comment: wait i will write your script ...

Comment: try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JB9Uq/4/)

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML well what you did with the {position:relative, top: -3px,
bottom: -1px;} is not working well and is the kind of css code that usually leads to other problems.

Comment: @burnedikt you're right it seems to be better with some fonts and worse with others. However I can't seem to find a solution that works for every font size even with the fonts that seems to fit better.

Comment: @MeykaEyl i have no more ideas to remove that ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what you looking for
 1. add a float left
 2. add height and line height

```
<div class="input-reference"><span>Content in span <a href="#"><i class="icon-remove">x</i></a></span><input type="text"></div>

input, textarea, span {
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.input-reference{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.input-reference:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.input-reference span,
.input-reference input{ 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 5px;

    /*adjust your height here*/
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.input-reference span{
    background-color: #53A9FF;  
    color: #fff;    
}
```

**UPDATE**

check jsfidle
http://jsfiddle.net/c5q7hauv/